# Unable to edit any columns in my C# DataGridView - would anyone know why?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to enabled editing for a number of columns in my DataGridView. Now, before anyone suggestions I should read the [MSDN article: How to: Specify the Edit Mode for the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yztkd864.aspx), I already have.

In summary (and I quote):

- The underlying data source supports editing.
- The DataGridView control is enabled.
- The EditMode property value is not EditProgrammatically.
- The ReadOnly properties of the cell, row, column, and control are all set to false.

All of that is simple and common sense. I've confirmed that the `Enabled = true`. I've confirmed that the `EditMode` is `EditOnKeystrokeOrF2` I've confirmed that all the columns (except one) are `ReadOnly = false`.

What I find interesting is the first line:-

> > The underlying data source supports editing.

Now, what I'm doing is the following, to bind the data to the DGV :-

```
// Grab all the Foos.
var foos = (from x in MyRepository.Find()
            select new
                      {
                          x.Foo1,
                          x.Foo2,
                          ...
                          x.FooN
                       }).ToList();

// Now lets bind this result to the GridView.
dataGridView2.DataSource = foos;
```

Which I thought was the right way to do things..

What i was planing on doing was, when the cell is changed and the user then *leaves* the cell, that's where I was planning on grabbing the data that was just changed (figure this out manually) and then manually update the DB.

Is this the right way to do things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, the underlying data source does not support editing since the properties of anonymous types are read only.  Per the C# language spec:

> The members of an anonymous type are a sequence of read-only properties inferred from the anonymous object initializer used to create an instance of the type.

Instead, you might want to define a display class with editable properties for the values you want to display and create instances of that class.

Comment: Not sure .. considering that i was *projecting* the results into an anonymous object. (notice the line `select new { .. }` <-- has no class defined.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with an unbound DGV.  I fixed it by setting the `ReadOnly` property of each ROW. Both the DGV and the Columns were not `ReadOnly`, but the Rows were somehow being set R/O perhaps when I set them using a collection.

So:

```
foreach (var r in Lst)
{
   ...
   dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].ReadOnly = false;
}
```